# Is a new blessing required when taking off and putting back on your tallit?

Tags: blessing, torah-service, tallit-gadol

You remove your tallit while services are ongoing (say, to go to the bathroom).  When you put it back on, do you have to say the blessing on the tallit again?

Comment: Related re: same question but Tefillin: https://dinonline.org/2011/04/07/tefillin-after-bathroom/

Answer (score 6):

This is a dispute recorded in [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 8:14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x354):

> אם פשט טליתו אפילו היה דעתו לחזור ולהתעטף בו מיד צריך לברך כשיחזור ויתעטף בו הגה וי"א  שאין מברכין אם יהיה דעתו לחזור ולהתעטף בו וי"א  דוקא  כשנשאר עליו  טלית קטן והכי נוהגין
>
> [R. Joseph Karo:] If he removed his *tallit* – even if his intent was to immediately put it back on – he needs to make a blessing when he puts it back on.
>
> [R. Moses Isserles:] And some say that he doesn't make a blessing if his intent was to put it back on. And some say [that this is] only when a *tallit katan* remains on him.

Comment: See [שו"ת אור יצחק ב:יב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=54963&st=&pgnum=8&hilite=) for an interesting suggestion on how to avoid the dispute.

Answer (score 3):

> If one removes the tallit or tzitzit (for instance, if one needs to
>   use the restroom during prayers), with the intention of donning the
>   same tallit or tzitzit afterwards, then it is not necessary to recite
>   the blessing again when putting it back on.
>   https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/530194/jewish/Do-I-Make-a-Second-Blessing-if-I-Took-Off-My-Tallit.htm

Comment: The article has no source for this assertion.

Comment: It’s Chabad so of course it comes from the Shulchan Aruch Harav see this link section 23 for the likely source of the Chabad Rabbi’s statement in this artiflr: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269356/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-8-Laws-Relating-to-Tzitzis-and-Enwrapping-Oneself-in-a-Tallis.htm

Answer (score 0):

No. The mitzvah of wearing a tallit gadol is only once a day, so if we take it off with the intention to put it back on soon, we do not make a new bracha when doing so. [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzitzit) cites sources arguing this is time based (within half an hour), while other sources suggest it is intention based (regardless of how long you are taking it off for, if your intention is to put it back on, you do not make the bracha again).

Please note that this reasoning does **NOT** apply to tefillin.

Comment: @  רבות, thank you for the info. Please see point 7.,   "If one removes one's Tallit and plans on putting it back on within half an hour, one does not recite a new bracha when putting it back on. [144]"

Comment: I stand corrected. Sorry.

Comment: Quite the contrary,  @ רבות, I couldn't fathom why my answer was being downvoted until you made your comment. Thank you!

Comment: there's still one downvoter, after i reversed mine...